# I could not understand the following paragraph's meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning, comprehension

**Source :-** The Office Season 6 Episode 9 (Murder)

**Transcript link :-** https://www.officequotes.net/no6-09.php

**Paragraph:-**

**Voice on CD player:** August the 5th, 1955. It’s a sad day down here in Savannah. Local magnate Bill Bourbon was killed last night and all y’all have congregated tonight for a **meal to celebrate Bill as he passes on to his great reward.** You’re not just here to pay your respects, you have to figure out which of y’all is the **no-count scoundrel** who killed him.

My doubts:-

Why is the crowd gathered to celebrate the death of a person , what reward are we talking about in this sentence ? and secondly what is a **no-count** scoundrel , I know the meaning of scoundrel which means a dishonest person but what is no-count used for

Comment: **no-count** is probably a dialect version of [**no-account**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-account).

Comment: It's **scoundrel**, not 'scroundel'!

Comment: @stangdon ,  I am still not able to get the meaning of that sentence , scoundrel of no importance , what would this mean ?

Comment: no-account means of no importance as per  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-account

Comment: @Fin27 I think it's an insult directed at the killer.  The speaker is saying that the killer is a worthless scoundrel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the crowd gathered to celebrate the death of a person

They are not gathered to celebrate his death, they are celebrating his life. *"...meal to **celebrate Bill** as he passes on..."*

> what reward are we talking about in this sentence

The "reward" is whatever happens after death. Presumably this person was well liked and respected, so the reward would be a good one (time in Heaven).

> and secondly what is a no-count scroundel

This means that they are not typically counted as a member of upstanding society and are deemed a "lower than human" that was accountable for his death.

Comment: I am not able to get the meaning of the last part of your explanation for no-count scoundrel , who are not counted as member of upstanding society ? sorry I am not a native speaker, could you rephrase the last sentence for more explanation thanks

Comment: @Fin27 The "no-count scoundrel" is the person(s) who committed the crime (murdering Bill). They are saying that anybody who attends is not just paying respects to Bill, but also there to help figure out who murdered him.

Answer (score 2):

"Great reward" is usually understood to mean **Heaven**, although it can be meant sarcastically to mean the other place, that is, **Hell**.